# How do I deploy an AngularJS app through Node.js without using Express?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have built an AngularJS app out of the basic Yeoman generator, and so far have been testing it locally through Grunt, using Node.js to write a simple web server that implements the APIs that some of the the app's functions need.

I wanted to extend my Node.js server functionality so that it would be able to serve all that is necessary to run my app locally for a later deployment through AWS. So far I've only been able to find tutorials that do this by using Express. Currently, my server code does not use Express and just runs out of the plain `createServer` method of the basic Node.js `http` module on port 8080.

What do I need to do to make it so that my AngularJS app can run out of this server without having to use Express? My main concern with Express is that I would need to rewrite a good deal of my server logic to fit it, starting from the APIs themselves.